# how to send image in notification in android using firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

I am trying to send image in push notification from firebase console but it doesn't work, so i tried to send from the postman but it doesn't work either. I tried other parameters like icon, image, media_url, mediaImgUrl..etc from Internet in the body.

Help me out here so that i can send image in notification.

```
{
       "to": "tokennnnnnnnnnnn............",
       "content_available": true,
       "mutable_content": true,
       "data":
       {
          "message": "Hey!",
          "icon": ".....farm.png"
       },
       "notification":
       {
          "body": "Topic",
          "sound": "default",
          "icon": ".....farm.png"
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try sending image with this payload :

```
{
  "message":{
    "token" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
     "android": {
       "notification": {
           "body" : "This is an FCM notification that displays an image.!",
           "title" : "FCM Notification",
           "image": "url-to-image"
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't work....later on i tried but it is throwing 401 error..asking for fcm token

Comment: please attach a screenshot of your postman request as well along with headers

Comment: I observed this closely and noticed only firebase url is working. So if you want to send any image notification first upload that image in firebase storage and then try using its image link.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
 "to" : "FCM_TOKEN",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification",
      "image": "image url"
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**